# How to remove custom extension and its entries from Database?

Tags: magento-1.7, extensions

I am developing a custom magento extension to add attributes and attribute sets when anyone extract the zip file and put that code to "/app" folder.

It makes several entries to database for atributes.
Now I am making further changes in attribute sets and want to install this module again.
So for this I am installing fresh version of magento to test the extension.
So any way to remove extension and its relavant entries from database?
I am not installing this extension from "Magento Connect Manager".

Answer (score 1):

If the Connect Manager does not pick your extension up, you need to remove those entries by hand or write an upgrade script removing them for you. The files need to be removed from app folder by hand anyways.
If you remove the extention and its entries by hand you need to remove it's entry from the `core_resource` table in Magento, too.

For more specific help you need to provide a little more information on how your module works.